# How to organize a large karaf blueprint.xml?

Tags: xml, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix, aries

I have a `blueprint.xml` for a camel app deployed in Karaf 3.5.6 under Servicemix which looks somewhat similar to what shown below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="jsonRPCProcessor"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.JSONRPCProcessor">
        <argument ref="myTemplate" />
        <argument>
            <map>

                <!-- Order Endpoints -->
                <entry key="getMarketplaceOrders" value-ref="getOrdersWFInfo" />
                <entry key="setStatusToReadyToShip" value-ref="setStatusToReadyToShipWFInfo" />
                <entry key="getOrderItemStatus" value-ref="getOrderItemStatusWFInfo" />
                <entry key="updateItemStatus" value-ref="updateOrderItemStatusWFInfo" />
                <entry key="createForwardManifest" value-ref="createForwardManifestWFInfo" />

                <!-- ERP Endpoints -->
                <entry key="ERP.insertSeller" value-ref="insertSellerWFInfo" />

            </map>
        </argument>
        <argument ref="exceptionHandler" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Order Beans -->

    <bean id="orderErrorResponseGenerator"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.OrderErrorResponseGenerator"></bean>

    <bean id="getOrdersWFInfo"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.WFInfo">
        <argument value="direct:getMarketplaceOrders" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request.GetMarketplaceOrdersRequest" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.response.OrderResponse" />
        <argument ref="orderErrorResponseGenerator" />
        <argument>
            <list>
                <value>100</value>
                <value>101</value>
            </list>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <bean id="setStatusToReadyToShipWFInfo"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.WFInfo">
        <argument value="direct:setStatusToReadyToShip" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request.UpdateOrderStatusReadyShipRequest" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.response.OrderResponse" />
        <argument ref="orderErrorResponseGenerator" />
        <argument>
            <list>
                <value>110</value>
                <value>111</value>
            </list>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <bean id="getOrderItemStatusWFInfo"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.WFInfo">
        <argument value="direct:getOrderItemStatus" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request.GetOrderItemStatusRequest" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.response.OrderResponse" />
        <argument ref="orderErrorResponseGenerator" />
        <argument>
            <list>
                <value>120</value>
                <value>131</value>
            </list>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <bean id="updateOrderItemStatusWFInfo"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.WFInfo">
        <argument value="direct:updateItemStatus" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request.UpdateOrderItemStatusRequest" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.response.UpdateOrderItemStatusResp" />
        <argument ref="orderErrorResponseGenerator" />
        <argument>
            <list>
                <value>140</value>
                <value>151</value>
            </list>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <bean id="createForwardManifestWFInfo"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.WFInfo">
        <argument value="direct:createForwardManifest" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request.CreateFwdManifestReq" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.response.OrderResponse" />
        <argument ref="orderErrorResponseGenerator" />
        <argument>
            <list>
                <value>151</value>
                <value>160</value>
            </list>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <bean id="orderHelper"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.OrderHelper">
        <property name="producer" ref="myTemplate" />
    </bean>



    <!-- ERP Beans -->
    <bean id="erpErrorResponseGenerator"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.erp.ERPErrorResponseGenerator"></bean>

    <bean id="insertSellerWFInfo"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.WFInfo">
        <argument value="direct:insertSeller" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.erp.request.InsertSellerRequest" />
        <argument
            value="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.erp.response.InsertSellerResponse" />
        <argument ref="erpErrorResponseGenerator" />
        <argument>
            <list>
                <value>10</value>
                <value>11</value>
            </list>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <bean id="erpHelper" class="com.orchestratorservice.adapter.erp.ERPHelper">
        <property name="producer" ref="myTemplate" />
    </bean>



    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="wf"
        update-strategy="none">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="order_update_item_status_sc_apiver"
                value="1" />
            <cm:property name="target_image_width" value="1400" />
            <cm:property name="target_image_height" value="1025" />

        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>


    <!-- a bean that uses a blueprint property placeholder -->

    <bean id="configBean"
        class="com.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.config.ConfigBean">
        <property name="order_update_item_status_sc_apiver" value="${order_update_item_status_sc_apiver}" />
        <property name="target_image_width" value="${target_image_width}" />
        <property name="target_image_height" value="${target_image_height}" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        useMDCLogging="true">
        <template id="myTemplate" />
        <route id="orchestrator-service-route">
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/orchestratorservice" />
            <process ref="jsonRPCProcessor" />
        </route>

        <!-- Order Routes -->
        <route id="get-orders-workflow">
            <from uri="direct:getMarketplaceOrders" />
            <to uri="bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders" />
        </route>
        <route id="set-status-readytoship-workflow">
            <from uri="direct:setStatusToReadyToShip" />
            <to uri="bean:orderHelper?method=setStatusToReadyToShip" />
        </route>
        <route id="get-order-itemstatus-workflow">
            <from uri="direct:getOrderItemStatus" />
            <to uri="bean:orderHelper?method=getOrderItemStatus" />
        </route>
        <route id="update-order-itemstatus-workflow">
            <from uri="direct:updateItemStatus" />
            <to uri="bean:orderHelper?method=updateItemStatus" />
        </route>
        <route id="create-forward-manifest-workflow">
            <from uri="direct:createForwardManifest" />
            <to uri="bean:orderHelper?method=createForwardManifest" />
        </route>

        <!-- ERP routes -->
        <route id="insert-seller-workflow">
            <from uri="direct:insertSeller" />
            <to uri="bean:erpHelper?method=insertSeller" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

In the blueprint we have different workflows modules defined ( for example in the above `blueprint.xml` - `order` & `ERP` ). Right now we are having a single `blueprint.xml` where we are defining all our workflows. This has become quite big (around 1000 lines already and we will add more).

Can some one please let me know

1. How do people organize large `blueprint.xml` like above?
2. Is it possible to have different xmls (for example in my case a different xml for `order` & `erp` module) and a single mother xml that combines all the child xmls?

Comment: If your blueprint file is so large then I think your bundle does too many things and should be split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All metadata from the blueprint files referenced by the Bundle are loaded and merged together :

- You can split this files into several small files
- I usually split the definitions by theme : In your case, probably one file with the camel route, another one with the configuration from ConfigurationAdmin, etc
- Aries-Blueprint has an extension with introspections/annotations which can help with the size of such files

Comment: Can you share some examples or links where file splitting example is shown? Also can you explain a bit more about the introspections / annotations?

Comment: I splited the file by theme ... all camel routes in one file, all processors in one file and separate xml for all beans in a module like a separate xml for all `order` beans, etc,